# how to make preg_replace for accented characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace some accented characters in php. First of all, i'm using `preg_match` to detect this kind (and it's working) of characters then `preg_replace` to replace them by an other one. In my case, I'm trying to replace `/[é]|[è]/` by `'e'`.

```
 if(preg_match('/[é]|[è]/',$adress)){
        preg_replace('/[é]|[è]/','e',$adress);
 }
```

So any alternatives or other solutions.

Comment: You forget the `/u` modifier. Just use `$adress = preg_replace('/[éè]/u','e',$adress);`

Comment: it's not working. The example : https://3v4l.org/8FshJ

Comment: It is working https://3v4l.org/0rMU4

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the variable `$adress` is passed to `preg_replace` *by value*. The line

```
preg_replace('/[é]|[è]/','e',$adress);
```

actually replaces the characters in *a temporary copy of* `$adress` variable. But the result is unused.

If you want to modify it, you should assign the result of `preg_replace` to it:

```
$adress = preg_replace('/[éè]/u', 'e', $adress);
```

Note the use of `u` flag. Also, I have slightly optimized the original regular expression.

Alternatively, use `str_replace`. It is not considered "multibyte", but it actually can be used for such replacements:

```
$adress = str_replace(['é', 'è'], 'e', $adress);
```

P.S.: consider renaming `$adress` to `$address`.